# Gulp del and / or runsequence causes localhost Wordpress to break but works after browser refresh

Tags: wordpress, gulp, localhost

I've built a gulp project that allows me to build and watch a wordpress theme (bones) in a wordpress installation that is outside the working folder:

```
Working folder: localhost/sites/testbed/
- dev-bones
- node_modules
- gulpfile.js
- package.json
- package-lock.json

Target folder: localhost/sites/my-wordpress-site/wp-content/themes/
- bones
```

I installed 'del' and 'run-sequence' so that I could delete the target folder before the build sequence began.

**del task:**

```
gulp.task('clean:dirbuild', function() {
  // If build directory is outside the working folder:
  return del.sync(dir.build, {force: true});
  // If inside:
  // return del.sync(dir.build);
});
```

**build task:**

```
gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
  runSequence('clean:dirbuild', 
    ['php', 'css', 'js', 'copyroot', 'copytranslation'],
    callback
  )
});
```

**default task:**

```
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```

After typing 'gulp watch' the browser launches and the wordpress site loads. But I get a white screen with a message saying that the path to bones.php doesn't exist.

I checked the target folder and it does exist.

After scratching my head for a while I manually refreshed the browser and the site loaded correctly.

I've gone through a number of permutations of the code above, always with the same result.

I found this post here on Stack Overflow : [run-sequence doesn't run gulp tasks in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197492/run-sequence-doesnt-run-gulp-tasks-in-order), but it didn't *seem* to fit my case.

I've uploaded the [full gulpfile to Github](https://github.com/chrisnajman/gulpfile).

I'd be very grateful if someone could give it the once-over and see where I'm going wrong.

UPDATE
I went back to a [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/#comment-1597401) I got the 'del' task from. In the comments the author had pointed out that he'd missed something from the task: the callback.

So I updated the code:

```
gulp.task('clean:dirbuild', function(callback) {
  // If build directory is outside the working folder:
  return del.sync(dir.build, {force: true}, callback);
  // If inside:
  // return del.sync(dir.build, callback);
});
```

and typed 'gulp'.

This time all I got was a white screen and manually refreshing didn't load the site.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. The problem was with the order of execution of the 'default' task: some of the 'watch' tasks where firing before, during and after the 'build' task.

So I left everything as it was except I changed:

**default task**

```
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```

to

```
gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
  runSequence('build', ['watch'], callback)
});
```

which ensures that the 'watch' task will run after the 'build' task.

Now, everything works as expected.

Note: I've deleted the example gulpfile.js from GitHub. When I've completed my project and got it on GitHub I'll post a link to it from here.